# Converting if statement to switch statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, html-lists

I need to convert the if statement in the function to a switch statement for an assignment. What the function needs to do is have the user input be a displayed list item when they press the submit button. When the number of inputs equals 5, it says "Thanks for your suggestions."

I included the original if statement as a comment.

I'm not sure where to go from here so that it works the same as the if statement.

```
    <article>
        <div id="results">
            <ul>
                <li id="item1"></li>
                <li id="item2"></li>
                <li id="item3"></li>
                <li id="item4"></li>
                <li id="item5"></li>
            </ul>
            <p id="resultsExpl"></p>
        </div>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="toolBox" id="placeLabel">
                    Type the name of a tool, then click Submit:
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="toolBox" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <button type="button" id="button">Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </article>
    <script>
        // global variables
        var i=1;
        var listItem = "";
        // function to add input to list
        function processInput() 
        {
            /*
            if (i<=5) 
            {
                listItem = "item" + i;
                document.getElementById(listItem).innerHTML = document.getElementById("toolBox").value;
                document.getElementById("toolBox").value = "";
                if (i==5) 
                {
                    document.getElementById("resultsExpl").innerHTML = "Thanks for your suggestions.";
                }
                i++;
            }
            */
            switch (i) {
                case 5:
                    document.getElementById("resultsExpl").innerHTML = "Thanks for your suggestions.";
                    break;
                case default:
                    listItem = "item" + i;
                    document.getElementById(listItem).innerHTML = document.getElementById("toolBox").value;
                    document.getElementById("toolBox").value = "";
                    i++;
            }
        }
        // adds backward compatible event listener to Submit button
        var submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
        if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
            submitButton.addEventListener("click", processInput, false);
        } else if (submitButton.attachEvent) {
            submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", processInput);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I asked for guidance, not an answer. Regardless, I was able to figure it out, but the case 5 doesn't seem to break. Any input after the 5th one replaces the last input. I'll keep messing around with it, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'll quote Douglas Crockford from: [Javascript the good parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do)

> The switch statement is a competent feature. Like most competent
>   features, it has loads of problems with it- the requirement of using
>   break after every statement within a case, procedural control flow,
>   out-of-place syntax, handling of code blocks, and much much more!
>   Unfortunately, solving these problems would require us to rewrite how
>   it operates at the core and the spec would entirely change, which, for
>   a language like JavaScript, would create massive backwards
>   compatibility issues.

Bottom line: Stick to if/else if/else statements.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I realized I put 'case default' instead of 'default'. I had to include some of the code from default to case 5 for it to display the last input as well as the message. I also placed i++ outside of the switch statement so that it stops after the 5th iteration but doesn't replace the last input.

```
switch (i) {
    case 5:
        listItem = "item" + i;
        document.getElementById(listItem).innerHTML = document.getElementById("toolBox").value;
        document.getElementById("toolBox").value = "";
        document.getElementById("resultsExpl").innerHTML = "Thanks for your suggestions.";
        break;
    default:
        listItem = "item" + i;
        document.getElementById(listItem).innerHTML = document.getElementById("toolBox").value;
        document.getElementById("toolBox").value = "";
}
i++;
```